# How do I save all received notifications on Android/IOS phone in my database using expo-notifications in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo-notifications

I'm coding in react native and I want to save all notifications that are received on Android/iOS in my database. I haven't started the database yet but I want the general code to see how to put all pending notifications in my firebase database.

The code I'm using so far is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));

  notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
    setNotification(notification);
  });

  responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });

  return () => {
    Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
    Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
  };
}, []);
```

Can you guys show me how to get all notifications and put in firebase database using expo-notifications.